# By convention, where do packages go to install on other machines?

Tags: tar, directory-structure, packaging

I'm working on a script that will scp a tarball to another machine and extract and install it's contents via ssh.  I have to install this script as one bash file and one tarball. I could install the scripts unpacked in the tarball, but I don't think that would be a good idea because they only run on a particular kind of device.

The tarball will be installed on other machines by users other than myself, so it needs to persist on that machine, the script doesn't need admin privileges to run.

Following our convention, the script I'm writing will most likely go in the /opt/bin folder, but where should the tarball that I'm copying be installed to on the machine that serves it up?

---

I probably just need reading this: http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html

Answer (score 2):

To confirm I follow you, there's the following items at play:

1. An installation script (for the various tools in the tarball)
2. A tarball with various tools packaged inside it (as shell scripts, some of which may not work with the parent OS)

I'll assume you are admin on the machine you are uploading to.

I think the right thing to do would be to put the installation script and tarball in your home folder, and then unpack the tools (scripts) to /opt/bin from there.

After I was done, I'd delete both the temp install script and the tarball from my home folder.

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to clarify just a little bit.  Users besides myself will run the script I am writing, I'm writing it so it will be there when they need it.  So I can't put it in my home folder and I need it to persist on the machine I'm putting it on.   The only thing I might do in the future with it is patch it.

Comment: Gotcha, well then I think Opt is probably a better place then for the script.  /opt/bin implies to me that the files there would be of type binary, which for a script wouldn't really be applicable.  The other common place for this kind of thing which I've seen is in /usr/local.  If your install script is architecture independent then perhaps /usr/local/share is better?   Back when I was paid for sysadmin work, the team I was on agreed to just put any custom scripts for the purposes of administration in /root.

Comment: Just to add a second voice here, `/opt` complies with FHS guidelines. +1 for `/opt`.